# Biometric Prompt on Android devices and Applicatioin authentication

Tags: android, android-biometric-prompt, android-biometric

I Would like to know more about the Biometric Authentication in Android.

First : How the the Biometric differentiate between all available authentications like face ID, Finger Print or Iris ???

Second: If user has registered face ID, Finger Print at device level. Then if my application implementing Biometric authentication, which one will it choose out of face ID & Finger Print ?

Thank you in advance!